# Dependency Injection in scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I have a trait

```
trait Tt[T]{
   //tens of methods
}
```

and

```
class St{ tt: Tt[T] =>
  type T = //...
  //some methods
}

object St{
    def apply[T](tt: Tt[T]) = new St with tt //error
}
```

The issue is the objects of `Tt` are generated by a library. Is there a way to avoid implementing all these tens of methods and just "inject the instance"?

I cannot just pass it as a parameter, because of the type variable declaration that is defined inside the class.

*Extracting the type variable declaration to the type parameter is not possible.*

Comment: "Not possible"? Breaking private key encryption is (at least theoretically, with quantum algorithms) possible, and moving a type declaration is not? :D
I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `class St(val tt: Tt[St#T]) { type T = ... }`

There is something else with your `apply` though: `St` wants the type parameter to `Tt` to be the same as it's own type `T` (you gotta start using more letters for these types), but `apply` is parametrized with `T`, which is yet another *different* type, that just happens to use the same letter. So, `def apply[T](tt: Tt[T]) = new St(tt)` won't compile, it needs to be `def apply(tt: Tt(St#T)) = new St(tt)`